# CodeIgniter standard code query is not returning result same like phpmyadmin result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeignitor framework and mysql for database,
But my problem is  CodeIgniter standard code query is not returning result same like php myadmin.

My php code is :

```
    $this->db->select('e_s_i.id as mnxmnxmcv, e_s_i.description aswoieurowieur');

    $this->db->where('t_b_z.zone_niscode', $nis_code);

    $this->db->join('tb_bldginstallerdetails b_i_d','b_i_d.installerdetails_companyid = e_s_i.id', 'left');

    $this->db->join('installer_zoning i_z', 'i_z.companyid = b_i_d.installerdetails_companyid', 'left');

    $this->db->join('tb_bldgzone t_b_z', 'i_z.zone = t_b_z.zone_zone', 'left');

    $query = $this->db->get('erit_service_installer e_s_i');

    $this->print_pre($query->row_array());exit;
```

After i execute my result is given below :

```
    Array
    (
    [mnxmnxmcv] => 13
    [aswoieurowieur] => Advanced Systems Communication Sdn Bhd
    )
```

But when print my sql query from php :

```
    SELECT `e_s_i`.`id` as mnxmnxmcv, 
      `e_s_i`.`description`    as     aswoieurowieur 
    FROM (`erit_service_installer` e_s_i) 
    LEFT JOIN `tb_bldginstallerdetails` b_i_d ON   `b_i_d`.`installerdetails_companyid` = `e_s_i`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `installer_zoning` i_z ON `i_z`.`companyid` = `b_i_d`.`installerdetails_companyid` 
    LEFT JOIN `tb_bldgzone` t_b_z ON `i_z`.`zone` = `t_b_z`.`zone_zone` 
    WHERE 
   `t_b_z`.`zone_niscode` = 'tifaw'
```

execute on phpmyadmin result output is different:

```
    mnxmnxmcv   woieurowieur
    41          Uniiii Streamiii Enterpriseq
```

Please let me know ,how to get same result

Thank you

Comment: Are you REALLY sure $nis_code are the same in both queries? You could hard code it in php while testing.

Comment: Hi @idstam, it is same in both queries, just now hardcoded my query with static niscode       $this->db->query('SELECT `e_s_i`.`id` as mnxmnxmcv, 
      `e_s_i`.`description`    as     aswoieurowieur 
    FROM (`erit_service_installer` e_s_i) 
    LEFT JOIN `tb_bldginstallerdetails` b_i_d ON   `b_i_d`.`installerdetails_companyid` = `e_s_i`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `installer_zoning` i_z ON `i_z`.`companyid` = `b_i_d`.`installerdetails_companyid` 
    LEFT JOIN `tb_bldgzone` t_b_z ON `i_z`.`zone` = `t_b_z`.`zone_zone` 
    WHERE 
   `t_b_z`.`zone_niscode` = 'tifaw'');  still getting incorrect result

Answer (score 0):

MySql is obviously not getting the same query.

First start by hard coding $nis_code in your PHP while testing so you know it's the same as in your plain sql query.

Are you selecting from the same database or cold you have mixed up your environments?

If you still get different data; remove all left  joins and select only from the 'master' table. Add the joins one at a time until you get the difference and ask here again when you can pin point the error.

Comment: Thanks, for reply @idstam, It was my fault, I was connecting to the wrong DB